# VBS Message Box

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

First off I'm sorry that i'm very very new to VBS, but i'm trying to create a little script that will complete a series of key strokes then on a website for work then go to another website and complete another series of key strokes.

Whilst on the first website there I need to ask a question like did the action complete. Yes or No.

If No then the script needs to go back to the start of the script.  If yes then the script needs to continue.

Later on, on the second website after a few keystrokes I need to ask another question weather to loop the whole process or to stop.

I've googled a few message box solutions but it doesn't seem to work.  I have

The first question box.

```
intSerialNumber = _
        Msgbox("Was there a problem?", _
            vbYesNo, "Problem?")

    If intSerialNumber = vbYes Then
        LoopShip
    Else
        Continue
    End If  

Continue
```

The Second question box.

```
 If msgbox("Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            WScript.quit
        End If
        if LoopShip = True Then
            LoopShip
    End If

Wend
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work".  Is it throwing an error?  If not what behavior is it doing that you don't want?

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested loops with functions for readability like this. The user can rerun the code from the first website as many times as they want and can rerun the code from both websites as many times as they want.

```
Dim problemsOccurred    
problemsOccurred = vbYes
Do
    Call firstWebsite()
    problemsOccurred = secondWebsite()
Loop Until (problemsOccurred = vbNo)


Sub firstWebsite()
    Dim firstWebsiteProblem
    firstWebsiteProblem = vbYes

    Do
        'First Website code Goes here
        firstWebsiteProblem = Msgbox("Was there a problem?", vbYesNo, "Problem?")
    Loop Until (firstWebsiteProblem = vbNo)

End Sub


Function secondWebsite()
    'Second WebSite code goes here
    secondWebsite = MsgBox("Continue Whole Process?", vbYesNo)
End Function
```